# Live USB keeps on loading

Tags: xubuntu, fsck

Recently when I switched on my laptop, I noticed that it went to (initramfs) and refuses to boot to my Xubuntu Desktop. So made a live usb drive with an image of Xubuntu and booted it.

It loaded in the first try and I ran fsck command on my ssd. It didn't show that it fixed it but nevertheless I removed the usb and tried booting it up again.

This time I got an error saying "Unable to set superflags". And I searched online and found a fix for it.
(https://linuxexpresso.wordpress.com/2010/03/31/repair-a-broken-ext4-superblock-in-ubuntu/)

But when I went to boot again from the live usb, it's not booting up. It keeps on loading. And when I press escape, it shows some "ACPI error"

Please help me fix this.

Comment: you may want to try the solutions related to being unable to boot: https://askubuntu.com/questions/162075/my-computer-boots-to-a-black-screen-what-options-do-i-have-to-fix-it

Comment: @Nmath I have gone through the link you sent and tried it all. None of them work.